# Expo stuck in Status: Queued while building the app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

My app build( expo react native) is stuck in `Status: Queued` while the app was building. Now the app is bult ( I see it in the logs) but the status is still `Status: Queued` and because of that I can't submit my app to the store as the build status is still in queue. Has this happened to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo has experienced some issues today. You can always check https://status.expo.dev/ to see the current status of eas. Try again when the issues are fixed. For me it started working again a few minutes ago.

Edit: The issues are now resolved and builds should now have correct status.